# Does commit or rollback turn autocommit on impliclitly in PHP's mysqli?

Tags: php, mysqli, commit, rollback, autocommit

I'm doing transactions in PHP with the mysqli class and I find the documentation of autocommit() woefully incomplete. 
I infer from the examples that setting autocommit to false implicitly performs a 'begin transaction'.  Is this correct?
More importantly, I don't see where autocommit gets reset to true which I assume it should be after a transaction is complete.  Does this happen automatically when commit() or rollback() methods are called?

Answer (score 2):

It does not implicitly perform a `START TRANSACTION`, because that performs ad-hoc transactions: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html

With `autocommit(false)`, any time you execute a write query you must `COMMIT` in order to have it update permanently on the disk.  This is true for all queries in that connection from then on.  With `autocommit(true)`, if you use `START TRANSACTION`, run an update, run `COMMIT`, and then run another update, *both* updates will be applied immediately (i.e. no second `COMMIT` is needed).

`autocommit` never gets reset to `true`, but it is only set per-session (MySQL session, not PHP session).

Comment: two points are still unclear.  If I set autocommit to false, do I then have to explicitly have to commit every write? Can I not set autocomplete to 'true' and avoid this?

Comment: Also, when you say "if you use START TRANSACTION, run an update, run COMMIT, and then run another..." do you have to call COMMIT to get the 1st update commited?  Shouldn't t;hid happen automatically?  Thanks

Comment: @Jim Yes to both questions.  `autocommit` is set to `true` by default though.  Just to be clear: if you set `autocommit` to true, it will not commit any outstanding queries; you must still run `COMMIT`.  I would suggest you not touch `autocommit` at all; just use transaction handling explicitly when you need it.

Answer (score 0):

Autocommit(FALSE) will stay false for the following queries. After you perform a commit-statement, the autocommit will revert back to true. Unsure of the rollback if it does the same.
I've been using this way for a few years and it has always worked fine.

When you want consistency in your db, this is one way to go.